# The modal is changing mi grid information (visually) when I press close or this get lost focus

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

The modal is changing my grid information (visually) when I press close or when I change the focus.
I already tried creating a temporary variable but it still doesn't work. I don't know how to solve this.

I don't want to lose information when I edit something and press save to display it. I do this so that I don't have to call my web service on every single edit.

**modal.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ProductoDetalle } from '../models/productoDetalle.model';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.page.scss'],
})
export class ModalPage implements OnInit {

  row;
  arreglo = ['end_date_active', 'start_date_active', 'fecha_actualizacion', 'usuario_actualizacion'];
  columnas: ProductoDetalle;
  rowTemp;

  constructor(public modalController: ModalController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) { }
  @Input() getdata;

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.filtraTextbox(this.arreglo, getdata2);
    this.row = this.getdata;
    this.rowTemp = this.getdata;
  }

  async alertConfirm(row: ProductoDetalle) {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Alerta!',
      message: '¿Desea <strong>guardar</strong> los cambios?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            this.rowTemp = this.row;
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Confirmar',
          handler: () => {
            this.row = this.rowTemp;
            this.modalController.dismiss({row});
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }

  async closeModal() {
    this.rowTemp = this.row;
    await this.modalController.dismiss();
  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
  }

filtraTextbox(key, datarray) {
    key.forEach( elemento => delete datarray[elemento] );
    return datarray;
  }

}
```

**modal.page.html**

```html
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title slot="start">Modificar Producto {{rowTemp.sku}}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="closeModal()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content> 
  <ion-item *ngFor="let col of rowTemp | keyvalue; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <ion-label position="stacked" color="tertiary">{{col.key}}</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="rowTemp[col.key]" required = true></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-button color="tertiary" (click)="alertConfirm(rowTemp)" slot="end" class="ion-margin-end">Guardar</ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Ok what do you want? Lol . The only think i understood was sorry about my english. In order to help you as you want, weite what tou want to let us know in google translator and write what tou want to achieve in your language and translate it to english,but now i really didn't understand anything even the code isn't understood well...

Comment: @MostafaHarb 
Currently my modal is changing the grid information (visually) when I close the modal or when I lose focus.
I want it to only show changes to the grid when I press the save button. 
Pressing save will send the data to the other component through the method "this.modalController.dismiss ({row});" in "async alertConfirm (row: ProductoDetalle))"

Comment: Ok, in the data sent from modal close, send an object back containing the index of item and data changed, and if they where multiple items return array comtaining multiple objects of item index and data to be changed, and on the onModal dismiss promise, and then make a for loop for the page array  and inside it make if statement to compare if array.index == returned array from modal index/indexes then set its data to new returned data